# Problem with TextEditingController on back pressed

Tags: flutter, textfield, onbackpressed, texteditingcontroller, constrainedbox

I have the following `StatefulWidget` in my Flutter application:

```
class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<EditProfilePage> createState() => _EditProfilePageState();
}

class _EditProfilePageState extends State<EditProfilePage> {
  ProfileClient client = ProfileClient();
  TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  Future<ProfileResponse>? futureProfileResponse;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureProfileResponse = fetch();
  }

  Future<ProfileResponse> fetch() async {
    String key = await Utils.getKey();
    return client.get(key);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    usernameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Edit profile'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                child: buildPage())));
  }

  FutureBuilder<ProfileResponse> buildPage() {
    return FutureBuilder<ProfileResponse>(
        future: futureProfileResponse,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            ProfileResponse profileResponse = snapshot.data!;
            if (profileResponse.code == 200) {
              usernameController.text = profileResponse.profile.username;
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      controller: usernameController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Username',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
}
```

I dont' understand the reason why, writing inside the username `TextField` and then pressing the back button, the content of the `TextField` comes back to the previous value.

This is a demo to make better understand my problem:
[Demo GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4VeP.gif)

To be precise, this problem started to appear as soon as I wrapped the `buildPage()` method with a `ConstrainedBox` widget. I did so because in my original page I had more `TextField` widgets and I needed them to "move up" when opening the keyboard. For the sake of simplicity, I removed parts of the code that were not related to this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user opens/closes the keyboard, the available screen size will change, which makes the widget rebuilds. The entire `FutureBuilder` will be rebuilt and the `builder` will execute the line where you assign the text to the controller. You can verify by adding a print statement right before it:

```dart
print('Widget rebuild at ${DateTime.now()}');
usernameController.text = profileResponse.profile.username;
```

The reason you use `FutureBuilder` is to render `TextField` only after the future completes and render `CircularProgressIndicator` otherwise. Setting the value for the controller should be separated from this widget building mechanism. You can set the `text` value for the controller in the `fetch` method:

```dart
Future<ProfileResponse> fetch() async {
  String key = await Utils.getKey();
  final profileResponse = client.get(key);
  usernameController.text = profileResponse.profile.username;
  return profileResponse;
}
```

In the `FutureBuilder`, remove this line:

```dart
usernameController.text = profileResponse.profile.username;
```

This way, the `usernameController.text` assignment line won't be called when the widget rebuilds.